# How to resolve the 'Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty' error in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

`Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource. Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

*error message*
[image]

*application.properties*
[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of this message. I have a DB name set in the application.properties. I have MongoDB running and I'm still getting this every time I try to start my server.

Answer (score 9):

Just your fellow learner here, following the same tutorial.

I jumped to the documentation and it seems you just have to add `/movie-api-db` at the end of your URI, to get access to the database collection:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<username>:<pwd>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/movie-api-db`

Hope, it'll help!

Comment: Dude you saved me. Very very thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else using Springboot 3.1.0 specifically, there is a solution offered in the github issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35566#issuecomment-1561295798).

Basically, `spring.data.mongodb.database` is ignored if you've set `spring.data.mongodb.uri`, which causes the error seen in the post. Adding the string template into the uri solves the issue.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/593fa1dc42177cc33b076643bd2ba6c66e84a3db) for version 3.1.1 which will be released at a later date.